# Faster way of scaling text in browser? (help interpret test)

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, performance-testing, css-transforms

I need to scale lots of text nodes in the browser (support of all modern desktop and mobile browsers).

If I am right there are two options that offer good performance: scaling text objects in Canvas or scaling text nodes in the DOM using `transform:matrix`.

I have created a scenario to test both versions but the results are inconclusive. Uncomment `testDOM()` or `testCanvas()` function to start the test. (I am using JQuery and CreateJS framework because it was convenient. It is possible to use vanilla JS but I don't think that is the bottleneck here). (It matters what portion of the screen you actually see so please switch to full screen view in codepen).

http://codepen.io/dandare/pen/pEJyYG

```
var WIDTH = 500;
var HEIGHT = 500;
var COUNT = 200;
var STEP = 1.02;
var MIN = 0.1;
var MAX = 10;
var stage;
var canvas;
var bg;
var canvasTexts = [];
var domTexts = [];
var domMatrix = [];
var dom;

function testDOM() {
    for (var i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
        var text = $("<div>Hello World</div>");
        var scale = MIN + Math.random() * 10;
        var matrix = [scale, 0, 0, scale, Math.random() * WIDTH, Math.random() * HEIGHT];
        text.css("transform", "matrix(" + matrix.join(',') + ")");
        domTexts.push(text);
        domMatrix.push(matrix);
    }
    dom = $('#dom');
    dom.append(domTexts);
    setTimeout(tickDOM, 1000);
}

function tickDOM() {
    for (var i = 0; i < domTexts.length; i++) {
        var text = domTexts[i];
        var matrix = domMatrix[i];
        var scale = matrix[0];
        scale *= STEP;
        if (scale > MAX)
            scale = MIN;
        matrix[0] = matrix[3] = scale;
        text.css("transform", "matrix(" + matrix.join(',') + ")");
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(tickDOM);
}

function testCanvas() {
    $('#dom').hide();
    stage = new createjs.Stage('canvas');
    createjs.Touch.enable(stage);
    createjs.Ticker.timingMode = createjs.Ticker.RAF;
    canvas = stage.canvas;
    devicePixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
    stage.scaleX = devicePixelRatio;
    stage.scaleY = devicePixelRatio;
    console.log('devicePixelRatio = ' + devicePixelRatio);
    stage.mouseMoveOutside = true;
    stage.preventSelection = false;
    stage.tickEnabled = false;
    stage.addChild(bg = new createjs.Shape());
    bg.graphics.clear();
    bg.graphics.f('#F2F2F2').drawRect(0, 0, 2 * WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    canvas.width = 2 * WIDTH * devicePixelRatio;
    canvas.height = HEIGHT * devicePixelRatio;
    canvas.style.width = 2 * WIDTH + 'px';
    canvas.style.height = HEIGHT + 'px';
    stage.update();
    for (var i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
        var text = new createjs.Text("Hello World", "10px", "#333333");
        text.scaleX = text.scaleY = MIN + Math.random() * 10;
        text.x = Math.random() * WIDTH;
        text.y = Math.random() * HEIGHT;
        stage.addChild(text);
        canvasTexts.push(text);
    }
    stage.update();
    setTimeout(tickCanvas, 1000);
}

function tickCanvas() {
    for (var i = 0; i < canvasTexts.length; i++) {
        var text = canvasTexts[i];
        text.scaleX = text.scaleY *= STEP;
        if (text.scaleX > MAX)
            text.scaleX = text.scaleY = MIN;
    }
    stage.update();
    requestAnimationFrame(tickCanvas);
}

testDOM();
//testCanvas();
```

My questions:

1. Is it possible to improve the performance of my tests? Am I doing something wrong?
2. The first 5-10 seconds are significantly slower but I don't understand why. Does the browser somehow cashes the text objects after some time? If yes, is the test unusable for real world scenario testing where the objects don't zoom in a loop for longer period of time?
3. According to the Chrome Profiling tool the DOM version leaves 40% more idle time (is 40% more faster) than the Canvas version but the Canvas animation looks much smoother (after the initial 5-10 seconds of lagging), how should I interpret the Profiling tool results?
4. In the DOM version I am trying to hide the parent of the text nodes before I apply the transformations and then unhide it but it probably does not matter because transform:matrix on absolutely positioned element does not cause reflow, am I right?
5. The DOM text nodes have some advantages over the Canvas nodes like native mouse over detection with `cursor: pointer` or support for decorations (you can not have underlined text in Canvas). Anything else I should know?
6. When setting the `transform:matrix` I have to create a string that the compiler must to parse back to numbers, is there a more efficient way of using `transform:matrix`?

Comment: One question ? What is the intended use of the scaled text? print? image? pdf? or just for the browser?

Answer (score 2):

**Q.1**

> Is it possible to improve the performance of my tests? Am I doing
>   something wrong?

Yes and no. (yes improve and no nothing inherently wrong (ignoring jQuery))

Performance is browser, and device dependent, for example Firefox handles objects better than arrays, while Chrome prefers arrays. There is a long list of differences just for the javascript.

Then the rendering is a dependent on the hardware, How much memory, what capabilities, and the particular drivers. Some hardware hates state changes, while others handle them at full speed. Limiting state changes can improve the speed on one machine while the extra code complexity will impact devices that don't need the optimisation.

The OS also plays a part.

---

**Q.2**

> The first 5-10 seconds are significantly slower but I don't understand
>   why. Does the browser somehow cashes the text objects after some time?
>   If yes, is the test unusable for real world scenario testing where the
>   objects don't zoom in a loop for longer period of time?

Performance testing in Javascript is very complicated and as a whole application (like your test) is not at all practical.

Why slow? 
Many reasons, moving memory to the display device, javascript optimising compilers that run while the codes runs and will recompile if it sees fit, this impacts the performance Un-optimised JS is SLOOOOOWWWWWWWW... and you are seeing it run unoptimised.

As well. In an environment like code pen you are also having to deal with all its code that runs in the same context as yours, it has memory, dom, cpu, GC demands in the same environment as yours and thus your code can not be said to be isolated and profiling results accurate.

---

**Q.3**

> According to the Chrome Profiling tool the DOM version leaves 40% more
>   idle time (is 40% more faster) than the Canvas version but the Canvas
>   animation looks much smoother (after the initial 5-10 seconds of
>   lagging), how should I interpret the Profiling tool results?

That is the nature of `requestAnimationFrame` (rAF), it will wait till the next frame is ready before it calls your function. Thus if you run 1ms past 1/60th of a second you have missed the presentation of the current display refresh and rAF will wait till the next is due 1/60th minus 1ms before presentation and the next request is called. This will result in ~50% idle time.

There is not much that can be done than make you render function smaller and call it more often, but then you will get extra overhead with the calls.

rAF can be called many times during a frame and will present all renders during that frame at the same time. That way you will not get the overrun idle time if you keep an eye on the current time and ensure you do not overrun the 1/60th second window of opportunity.

---

**Q.4**

> In the DOM version I am trying to hide the parent of the text nodes
>   before I apply the transformations and then unhide it but it probably
>   does not matter because transform:matrix on absolutely positioned
>   element does not cause reflow, am I right?

Reflow will not be triggered until you exit the function, hiding the parent at the start of a function and then unhiding it at the end will not make much difference. Javascript is blocking, that means nothing will happen while you are in a function.

---

**Q.5**

> The DOM text nodes have some advantages over the Canvas nodes like
>   native mouse over detection with cursor: pointer or support for
>   decorations (you can not have underlined text in Canvas). Anything
>   else I should know?

That will depend on what the intended use is. DOM offers a full API for UI and presentation. Canvas offers rendering and pixel manipulation. The logic I use is if it takes more code to do it via DOM then canvas, then it is a canvas job and visa versa

---

**Q.6**

> When setting the transform:matrix I have to create a string that the
>   compiler must to parse back to numbers, is there a more efficient way
>   of using transform:matrix?

No. That is the CSS way.